Would native speakers use "forefather" when speaking about history or is it too literary?
I want to say:

My forefathers were badass for defeating the enemies in those bloody wars.

I have two concerns:

Is "forefathers" too literary for speaking?
Is it correct to use "badass" to show that I think my ancestors were really cool for defeating all the invaders?


What is the relevant locale? "Bad-ass" is much less common in British English than in the US

Register clash:  forefathers and badass.  Also "badass for {some achievement}" isn't how it's used.

So how is it used? What's wrong with "badass for skme achievement"?

A person is or is not a badass, just like they are or are not a fool, or a scoundrel, or a cad, or a saint.  The saint does saintly things. A badass does badass stuff. But they're not a badass for what they do.  It's who they are.

Wait, so saying "You're a total fool for believing him" is also unnatural?

No, I don't mean to say that. I was trying to find intrinsic qualities. But sometimes those intrinsic qualities are not used as such but to describe particular acts.  "You're a saint for helping us out." But we don't say "You're a badass for standing up to those guys."  It's not ungrammatical, just not how "badass" is used.  But we might say to someone who has just stood up to some bullies, 'That was badass!"

It would be natural enough to use "forefathers" in a conversation in which the word, or the topic of family history was already under discussion.  So look to the context in which you are speaking.  Was this in answer to a question?
There is an element of bathos in the contrast from "forefathers" to "badass".  Because "badass" is pretty casual.
So, native speakers do say the word "forefathers", it's not exceptionally formal.  However "ancestors" might be a better option for multiple reasons, for example "forefathers" is gendered.  Were there no women who were also badass?

If you really want to milk the bathos, there's "foreparents" (note: this is not actually a word. That's why it's bathetic)

@NoName: You want bathos? I'll show you bathos: "Learn ye the hash pivot tesuji" (Something I said that almost got written down before)

"Were there no women who were also badass?".  No... they were too busy doing all the mundane work needed to keep a house running.
